# Collapse elements separated by ""

Tags: r

I have raw bibliographic data as follows:

```
bib = 
c("Bernal, Martin, \\\"Liu Shi-p\\'ei and National Essence,\\\" in Charlotte", 
    "Furth, ed., *The Limit of Change, Essays on Conservative Alternatives in", 
    "Republican China*, Cambridge: Harvard University Press, 1976.", 
    "", "Chen,Hsi-yuan, \"*Last Chapter Unfinished*: The Making of the *Draft Qing", 
    "History* and the Crisis of Traditional Chinese Historiography,\"", 
    "*Historiography East & West*2.2 (Sept. 2004): 173-204", "", 
    "Dennerline, Jerry, *Qian Mu and the World of Seven Mansions*, New Haven:", 
    "Yale University Press, 1988.", "")

[1] "Bernal, Martin, \\\"Liu Shi-p\\'ei and National Essence,\\\" in Charlotte"
 [2] "Furth, ed., *The Limit of Change, Essays on Conservative Alternatives in" 
 [3] "Republican China*, Cambridge: Harvard University Press, 1976."            
 [4] ""                                                                         
 [5] "Chen,Hsi-yuan, \"*Last Chapter Unfinished*: The Making of the *Draft Qing"
 [6] "History* and the Crisis of Traditional Chinese Historiography,\""         
 [7] "*Historiography East & West*2.2 (Sept. 2004): 173-204"                    
 [8] ""                                                                         
 [9] "Dennerline, Jerry, *Qian Mu and the World of Seven Mansions*, New Haven:" 
[10] "Yale University Press, 1988."                                             
[11] ""
```

I would like to collapse elements between the `""`s in one line so that:

```
clean_bib[1]=paste(bib[1], bib[2], bib[3])
clean_bib[2]=paste(bib[5], bib[6], bib[7])
clean_bib[3]=paste(bib[9], bib[10])

[1] "Bernal, Martin, \\\"Liu Shi-p\\'ei and National Essence,\\\" in Charlotte Furth, ed., *The Limit of Change, Essays on Conservative Alternatives in Republican China*, Cambridge: Harvard University Press, 1976."
[2] "Chen,Hsi-yuan, \"*Last Chapter Unfinished*: The Making of the *Draft Qing History* and the Crisis of Traditional Chinese Historiography,\" *Historiography East & West*2.2 (Sept. 2004): 173-204"                
[3] "Dennerline, Jerry, *Qian Mu and the World of Seven Mansions*, New Haven: Yale University Press, 1988."
```

Is there a one-liner that does this automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tapply` while grouping with all `""` then paste together the groups

```
  unname(tapply(bib,cumsum(bib==""),paste,collapse=" "))
[1] "Bernal, Martin, \\\"Liu Shi-p\\'ei and National Essence,\\\" in Charlotte Furth, ed., *The Limit of Change, Essays on Conservative Alternatives in Republican China*, Cambridge: Harvard University Press, 1976."
[2] " Chen,Hsi-yuan, \"*Last Chapter Unfinished*: The Making of the *Draft Qing History* and the Crisis of Traditional Chinese Historiography,\" *Historiography East & West*2.2 (Sept. 2004): 173-204"               
[3] " Dennerline, Jerry, *Qian Mu and the World of Seven Mansions*, New Haven: Yale University Press, 1988."                                                                                                          
[4] ""
```

you can also do:

```
  unname(c(by(bib,cumsum(bib==""),paste,collapse=" ")))
```

or

```
 unname(tapply(bib,cumsum(grepl("^$",bib)),paste,collapse=" "))
```

etc

Comment: Ahh... I think I get it.

Comment: try running `cumsum(bib=="")` and see what it gives. so this will be the groupings. Ie the first three 0 indicate that the first three strings should be grouped together, the next 4 ones indicate that the next four strings should als be grouped together, the three 2's indicate that the next three strings should be grouped together. Now we use `tapply` to do this

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the other answer. This uses `split` and `sapply`. The second line is just to remove any elements with only has "".

```
vec <- unname(sapply(split(bib, f = cumsum(bib %in% "")), paste0, collapse = " "))
vec[!vec %in% ""]
```